# ASP .Net WebAPI End-To-End performance monitoring

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I work with a fairly large WebAPI web service, and we have started to discuss performance monitoring.

The idea is to capture the End-To-End performance, which for our WebAPI would include a TCP connection, SSL handshake, F5 firewall and load balancing, and WebAPI receiving the request and sending the response. I think we are more concerned with receiving, processing, and sending data than the connection establishment.

My (maybe misguided) question is this:

**If I were to capture the Start and End times for requests using
Application_BeginRequest and _EndRequest, would that essentially
account for End-To-End timing?**

In other words, disregarding the (probably minimal) times it would take to establish the connection from the client to the WebAPI, would the BeginRequest and EndRequest methods account for receiving the entire HttpRequest from the client, processing the WebAPI methods, and sending the entire HttpResponse to the client?

Would that get me close to measuring the total time it takes a client to send a request to the server (with possibly large body data), processing time, and time to send the response to the client (with large body data)? Or would I be missing a large part of the receiving and sending?

Answer (score 1):

No, BeginRequest isn't the first event in the pipeline.  There are several steps and processes that occur outside of the BeginRequest within IIS.  See this article for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx

A helpful, and free tool for you to visualize the process and provide profiling on your development system is available from Stackify. Check out [Prefix](http://stackify.com/prefix), it can provide you full timing information on your development system.

In production, you can use other solutions, such as Stackify's production monitoring and profiling, or [New Relic](http://newrelic.com)